# How to decode compressed data into ASCII art?

Tags: python

For my NIA im working on a program which in which the user enters compressed code in a form such as

```
01,01a01d57801d01a01,
01d61 01b
01845 01,01a01d10801 01801 018
```

And it will print out as an ASCII art image. I am incredibly confused by the whole idea and would accept any helpful pieces of code.

Comment: Could you add an example of what you want as an output?

Comment: Googling `01,01a01d57801d01a01,` yields some results about run-length encoding, FWIW.